# Error: Package: perl-Git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64 (epel) Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8)

Tags: git, ffmpeg, libtool

error in loading github lib tool

i have tried to load the following dependencies to load  ffmpeg from source when i try to run the following command i am getting errors as below

```
yum install autoconf automake gcc gcc-c++ git libtool make nasm pkgconfig zlib-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.viethosting.vn
 * epel: ftp.cuhk.edu.hk
 * extras: mirrors.viethosting.vn
 * updates: mirrors.vinahost.vn
base                                                     | 3.7 kB     00:00     
epel                                                     | 3.7 kB     00:00     
epel/primary_db                                          | 3.7 MB     00:18     
extras                                                   | 3.4 kB     00:00     
updates                                                  | 3.4 kB     00:00     
updates/primary_db                                       | 1.5 MB     00:16     
vz-base                                                  |  951 B     00:00     
vz-updates                                               |  951 B     00:00     
Setting up Install Process
Package autoconf-2.63-5.1.el6.noarch already installed and latest version
Package automake-1.11.1-4.el6.noarch already installed and latest version
Package gcc-4.4.7-11.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package gcc-c++-4.4.7-11.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package 1:make-3.81-20.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package 1:pkgconfig-0.23-9.1.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package zlib-devel-1.2.3-29.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package git.x86_64 0:1.8.2.1-1.el5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl-Git = 1.8.2.1-1.el5 for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Term::ReadKey) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Git) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Error) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.6()(64bit) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libexpat.so.0()(64bit) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcurl.so.3()(64bit) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.6()(64bit) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
---> Package libtool.x86_64 0:2.2.6-15.5.el6 will be installed
---> Package nasm.x86_64 0:2.07-7.el6 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package compat-expat1.x86_64 0:1.95.8-8.el6 will be installed
---> Package git.x86_64 0:1.8.2.1-1.el5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libcurl.so.3()(64bit) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
---> Package openssl098e.x86_64 0:0.9.8e-18.el6_5.2 will be installed
---> Package perl-Error.noarch 1:0.17015-4.el6 will be installed
---> Package perl-Git.x86_64 0:1.8.2.1-1.el5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8) for package: perl-Git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
---> Package perl-TermReadKey.x86_64 0:2.30-13.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: perl-Git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8)
Error: Package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libcurl.so.3()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

now i went into some solution on net which asked to check with disablerepo to rpmforge it also throw the following error

```
# yum --disablerepo=rpmforge install git
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror


Error getting repository data for rpmforge, repository not found
```

kindly help so that i can install all the dependencies so that i may not face any problem while configuring ffmpge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this through the following commands:

```
wget http://mirror.umd.edu/fedora/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
sudo yum remove epel-release
sudo rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm --test
sudo rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
sudo yum update








 yum install autoconf automake gcc gcc-c++ git libtool make nasm pkgconfig zlib-devel  --skip-broken 
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.viethosting.vn
 * epel: mirrors.vinahost.vn
 * extras: mirrors.viethosting.vn
 * updates: mirrors.vinahost.vn
Setting up Install Process
Package autoconf-2.63-5.1.el6.noarch already installed and latest version
Package automake-1.11.1-4.el6.noarch already installed and latest version
Package gcc-4.4.7-11.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package gcc-c++-4.4.7-11.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package 1:make-3.81-20.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package 1:pkgconfig-0.23-9.1.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package zlib-devel-1.2.3-29.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package git.x86_64 0:1.8.2.1-1.el5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl-Git = 1.8.2.1-1.el5 for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Term::ReadKey) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Git) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Error) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.6()(64bit) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libexpat.so.0()(64bit) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcurl.so.3()(64bit) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.6()(64bit) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
---> Package libtool.x86_64 0:2.2.6-15.5.el6 will be installed
---> Package nasm.x86_64 0:2.07-7.el6 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package compat-expat1.x86_64 0:1.95.8-8.el6 will be installed
---> Package git.x86_64 0:1.8.2.1-1.el5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libcurl.so.3()(64bit) for package: git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
---> Package openssl098e.x86_64 0:0.9.8e-18.el6_5.2 will be installed
---> Package perl-Error.noarch 1:0.17015-4.el6 will be installed
---> Package perl-Git.x86_64 0:1.8.2.1-1.el5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.8.8) for package: perl-Git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64
---> Package perl-TermReadKey.x86_64 0:2.30-13.el6 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libtool.x86_64 0:2.2.6-15.5.el6 will be installed
---> Package nasm.x86_64 0:2.07-7.el6 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libtool.x86_64 0:2.2.6-15.5.el6 will be installed
---> Package nasm.x86_64 0:2.07-7.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    compat-expat1-1.95.8-8.el6.x86_64 from base
    git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64 from epel
    openssl098e-0.9.8e-18.el6_5.2.x86_64 from base
    1:perl-Error-0.17015-4.el6.noarch from base
    perl-Git-1.8.2.1-1.el5.x86_64 from epel
    perl-TermReadKey-2.30-13.el6.x86_64 from base

Dependencies Resolved

==================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                         Arch                                  Version                                          Repository                           Size
==================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 libtool                                         x86_64                                2.2.6-15.5.el6                                   base                                564 k
 nasm                                            x86_64                                2.07-7.el6                                       base                                386 k
Skipped (dependency problems):
 compat-expat1                                   x86_64                                1.95.8-8.el6                                     base                                 60 k
 git                                             x86_64                                1.8.2.1-1.el5                                    epel                                7.4 M
 openssl098e                                     x86_64                                0.9.8e-18.el6_5.2                                base                                761 k
 perl-Error                                      noarch                                1:0.17015-4.el6                                  base                                 29 k
 perl-Git                                        x86_64                                1.8.2.1-1.el5                                    epel                                 49 k
 perl-TermReadKey                                x86_64                                2.30-13.el6                                      base                                 31 k

Transaction Summary
==================================================================================================================================================================================
Install       2 Package(s)

Total download size: 950 k
Installed size: 3.1 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
(1/2): libtool-2.2.6-15.5.el6.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                   | 564 kB     00:04     
(2/2): nasm-2.07-7.el6.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                          | 386 kB     00:02     
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                                                                                                             114 kB/s | 950 kB     00:08     
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
  Installing : libtool-2.2.6-15.5.el6.x86_64                                                                                                                                  1/2 
  Installing : nasm-2.07-7.el6.x86_64                                                                                                                                         2/2 
  Verifying  : nasm-2.07-7.el6.x86_64                                                                                                                                         1/2 
  Verifying  : libtool-2.2.6-15.5.el6.x86_64                                                                                                                                  2/2 

Installed:
  libtool.x86_64 0:2.2.6-15.5.el6                                                             nasm.x86_64 0:2.07-7.el6                                                            

Skipped (dependency problems):
  compat-expat1.x86_64 0:1.95.8-8.el6    git.x86_64 0:1.8.2.1-1.el5  openssl098e.x86_64 0:0.9.8e-18.el6_5.2  perl-Error.noarch 1:0.17015-4.el6  perl-Git.x86_64 0:1.8.2.1-1.el5 
  perl-TermReadKey.x86_64 0:2.30-13.el6 

Complete!
```